# What is the best to detect stderr output and stop make

Tags: shell, makefile

My Makefile runs a program which, when it finds problem in input files, just dumps the error message to stderr but still returns zero. Here is the Makefile snippet:

```
target:
    prog1 -i input1 input2 -o out.txt
    prog2
```

"prog1" is the program and here is my fix:

```
target:
    prog1 -i input1 input2 -o out.txt  2>&1  1>/dev/null | tee err_log
    if [ -s err_log ]; then false ; fi
    prog2
```

Basically I redirect stderr to file err_log and detect if err_log is not empty. I also want the error message to display in console.

These all work, but there is one minor annoyance: the `false` command, `if [ -s err_log ]; then false ; fi` shows in console and it is at the end of the console.

I wonder if in the place of false command I could just stop the make but with no message going to console? Basically I want the stderr message at the end.

Comment: `false` only sets the return status. Maybe you want `exit 1` to terminate processing? Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell `make` to not print the command it runs by prepending the recipe line with the `@` character:

```
target:
        prog1 -i input1 input2 -o out.txt  2>&1  1>/dev/null | tee err_log
        @if [ -s err_log ]; then false ; fi
        prog2
```

FYI, you can just use:

```
        @[ ! -s err_log ]
```

to get the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use as few auxiliary files as possible.  They are a source of additional problems you may need to develop workarounds to.

If you just want to test whether any output is being produced, you can use `grep`.

You also need to declare your output file to be the target and your input files to be dependencies.

So this should do the trick:

```
out.txt: input1 input2
    prog1 -i $+ -o $@ 2>&1 | grep -q .
    prog2
```

However, you should really have a separate rule to run `prog2` as it probably depends on `out.txt`.  Something like

```
out.txt: input1 input2
    prog1 -i $+ -o $@ 2>&1 | grep -q .

whatever: out.txt
    prog2
```

If `prog2` has and output file and input files, make them the target and dependencies as well.